# Test a React app that uses Firebase Auth in javascript

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, testing, jestjs

I import the Login component to test and I get this error

```
 ● Test suite failed to run

    FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Can't determine Firebase Database URL. Be sure to include  a Project ID when calling firebase.initializeApp().
```

So far I have this

```
import React from "react";
import { render} from "@testing-library/react/pure";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import Login from "../src/components/auth/Login";
import * as firebase from "@firebase/testing";

const PROJECT_ID = "connect-four-development";

describe("Login", () => {
  it("renders Login.js without crashing", async () => {
    await firebase.initializeTestApp({ projectId: PROJECT_ID }).firestore();

    render(
        <Login />
    );
  });
});
```

How should I initialize the app properly for testing?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the `config` from your Projects Firebase Console. It looks like this:

```js
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "API_KEY",
  authDomain: "PROJECT_ID.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://PROJECT_ID.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "PROJECT_ID",
  storageBucket: "PROJECT_ID.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "SENDER_ID",
  appId: "APP_ID",
  measurementId: "G-MEASUREMENT_ID",
};
```

You can find your project config in the Console under: Project Settings -> General. There you should create a Web App and you will get a nice instruction how to initialize your app and with it the configuration.

And you initialize your app like so:

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
  // ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

For the test suite there are specific initalizations.

Cloud Firestore:

```js
firebase.initializeTestApp({
  projectId: "my-test-project",
  auth: { uid: "alice", email: "alice@example.com" }
});
```

RTDB:

```js
firebase.initializeTestApp({
  databaseName: "my-database",
  auth: { uid: "alice" }
});
```

and Storage:

```js
firebase.initializeTestApp({
  storageBucket: "my-bucket",
  auth: { uid: "alice" }
});
```

You can also change yout code to:

```js
describe("Login", () => {
  it("renders Login.js without crashing", async () => {
    firebase.initializeTestApp({ projectId: PROJECT_ID })
    firebase.firestore();

    render(
        <Login />
    );
  });
});
```

The app initialization is synchronous.

Comment: I actually initialized the app already and the app is done. I meant to only ask how to initialize for test suite. So there shouldn't be a project ID problem since my app works fine. I've tried your syntax and it still gives the same error. Is there specific docs that you can point me to? I cannot find anything on authentication. Mostly for security rules.

Comment: Here is the documentation for the Realtime Database Emulator: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_rtdb#node.js-admin-sdk

Comment: I got passed the Project ID error above after setting up the emulator, but now I have the another error.                                                                                              ● Test suite failed to run

    Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.

        "code": "auth/invalid-api-key",
        "message": "Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.",
      }

Comment: Can you pls ask that as a new question on stack overflow. That way other can find it easier if the run into the same one. thx